# Generate a Signature for Testing Verification

Tags: sendgrid, ecdsa

I am creating an API to be the target of a webhook (Twilio Sengrid's event webhook) and I want to use signed verification. They provide me with a public key that I can use to verify their requests. I have implemented the verification flow to my code and it is working all well and good.  However, I would like to continue testing my API by sending my own messages via Postman.  This requires me to have a signature and timestamp that will be used to verify against the public key and the message sent. Is it possible to generate the signature without the private key?